# Unable to Get Fully-Qualified Type Name from Javadoc Element

Tags: java, gradle, annotations, javadoc

Short and sweet: despite the fact that I am asking the Javadoc API to give me the fully-qualified name of an annotation, it is only returning the simple type name.

I am writing a Javadoc doclet that relies heavily on the inspection of annotations. As such, I have created a utility function that will take an array of [`AnnotationDesc`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/javadoc/doclet/com/sun/javadoc/AnnotationDesc.html) objects and return a `Map` that associates the fully-qualified name of the annotation to the `AnnotationDesc` object that describes it. Here are the relevant functions:

```
public static final Map<String, AnnotationDesc> getAnnotationMap(AnnotationDesc[] notes)
{
    if (notes == null)
    {
        return Collections.emptyMap();
    }

    return Collections.unmodifiableMap(Arrays.stream(notes).collect(Collectors.toMap(AnnotationUtils::getNoteName, note -> note)));
}

private static String getNoteName(AnnotationDesc note) { return note.annotationType().qualifiedTypeName(); }
```

For what it's worth, I have also tried using `qualifiedName`, which is another method exposed by the return value of the `AnnotationDesc.annotationType` method.

In my integration tests, this is all working great. However, when I push my doclet out to Artifactory, pull it down into another project and try to invoke it by way of a Gradle task, the keys in my map are the simple type names of the annotations.

Here is the definition of my Gradle task:

```
task myDocletTask(type: Javadoc) {
    source = sourceSets.main.allJava
    destinationDir = reporting.file("my-doclet-dir")
    options.docletpath = configurations.jaxDoclet.files.asType(List)
    options.doclet = <redacted - fully qualified type name of custom doclet>
}
```

I have noticed that if a program element is annotated with a fully-qualified annotation, then the fully-qualified name is actually picked up by the Javadoc API. E.g: `@com.package.Annotation` results in the expected behavior, but `@Annotation` does not.

Can someone please help me to understand why this is happening and, more importantly, how I can achieve the expected/desired behavior?

Comment: -Where does the AnnotationUtils class come from?- ah, I see it's the containing class, and the getNoteName method is below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the annotations were not on the classpath of the doclet at "documentation time". In order to fix this problem I augmented my Gradle Javadoc task with the following line: `options.classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath.asType(List)`.